# Usage of let me

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, american-english, sentence-usage

I have heard people use the following sentence:
Scenario I am talking to the other person and he says `There is some lag. Let me check my internet connection` Is this usage of `Let me check...` correct. It sounds like as if someone is taking permission from the other person. I have seen people frequently used `Let me ..` in everyday English.

Comment: For this particular usage: In most situations, an American is likely to pronounce this as "Lemme," a spelling commonly used in fictional dialogue. If you are speaking to someone performing a task that requires some mental effort (typing, examining your automobile engine, etc.) they might draw it out slowly: "Lehht . . . meee . . . chehhhck . . . " In this case, the "t" at the end of "let" might be pronounced as a real "t" or as a glottal stop (like the "t" sound in "button").

Answer (score 2):

'Let me...' in that kind of situation is just conventional conversational politeness and means, roughly, 'please allow me the time to *do something*'. By 'conventional' I mean that the speaker is not really seeking permission to take the time to do something; he or she is just politely pretending to do so.